# Pandas não lê corretamento o json

Tags: python, pandas

possui um json com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Title": "Serviços - Eventos",
                "STATUS": "INICIADA",
                "DESCRICAO": "Descrição 1"
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Title": "Serviços - Externas",
                "STATUS": "INICIADA",
                "DESCRICAO": "Descrição 2"
            }
        ],
        "__next": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Eu consigo fazer o request normalmente, porém, quando eu tento converter em um dataframe `pd.read_json()` o pandas me retorna o seguinte:

```
d
__next  https://xxxxxx...
results [{'id': '1'...
```

o **d** fica como a coluna e o **__next** e **results**, junto com seus values entram na linha.

Também já tentei realizar o parse abaixo, mas não consegui:

```
r = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
json = json.load(r.text)
```

tentei com o load e o loads e aparece o seguinte erro:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load'

Alguém pode me ajudar a identificar o erro?

Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está encontrando este erro pois seu `json` contém vários dicionários, e para ler como um `dataframe` é preciso somente do dicionário onde estão os dados da tabela.

Utilizando o parâmetro `typ` em `pd.read_json`, podemos selecionar o tipo do objeto a ser retornado, então ao invés de retornar um `frame`, vamos retornar o tipo `series`:

```
df = pd.read_json('json.json',typ='series')
```

Isso retornará o `json` completo, adicionando um *slice* na serie com `df = pd.read_json('json.json',typ='series')[0]`, teremos como resultado:

```
{'results': [{'Id': 1,
   'Title': 'Serviços - Eventos',
   'STATUS': 'INICIADA',
   'DESCRICAO': 'Descrição 1'},
  {'Id': 2,
   'Title': 'Serviços - Externas',
   'STATUS': 'INICIADA',
   'DESCRICAO': 'Descrição 2'}],
 '__next': 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
```

E a sua tabela está justamente na chave `'results'`, então basta adicionar também a chave como *slice* e utilizar o método `pd.Dataframe()` para converter em tabela:

```
df = pd.read_json('json.json',typ='series')[0]['results']
pd.DataFrame(df)
df.set_index('Id')  # Definir coluna Id como índice
```

Resultado:

| Id | Title | STATUS | DESCRICAO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Serviços - Eventos | INICIADA | Descrição 1 |
| 2 | Serviços - Externas | INICIADA | Descrição 2 |

Comment: Essa resposta resolve o caso específico, eu acrescentaria  comentário de que para casos genéricos , se você quer converter um json pra uma tabela, mas você tem dicionários dentro de dicionários, existem métodos chamados json flatten que resolve renomeando as colunas de forma que elas carregam informações. Por exemplo, a coluna `id` poderia ser transformada em `d.results.id` etc

Comment: Felipe, super obrigado pela sua resposta, porém, retornou o seguinte erro `'dict' object has no attribute 'set_index'` justamente na linha `df.set_index('Id')  # Definir coluna Id como índice`

Comment: Você converteu para DataFrame antes de utilizar `set_index`?

Comment: Fiz exatamente como você colocou lá na resposta, ficou assim:
`r = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)` - 
`df = pd.read_json(api_url, storage_options=headers, typ='series')[0]` - 
`pd.DataFrame(df)` - 
`df.set_index()  # Definir coluna Id como índice`

Comment: Tente remover linha onde o *pandas* lê o *json* e ir direto para a linha `df = pd.DataFrame(r['d']['results'])` - `df.set_index('Id')`. Assim deve funcionar Renan.

Comment: Consegui Felipe! Mano, super obrigado!!!!